Adding 点儿 to an adjective
Adding 一点儿 to an adjective gives it a sense of comparison.
Like 大一点儿 "a little bigger",  低一点儿 "a little lower"
However, in the sentence "他年龄大了点儿，他文化低了点儿"
I can't figure out the meaning. Does it mean "He is a bit old, education a bit low."
If this meaning is meant, I guess "他年龄有点儿大，他文化有点儿低" is a better choice.
I also don't know the function of 了 here?   If 了 conveys "change of situation" then why shouldn't one say "他年龄大点儿了 ，他文化低点儿了 "?
Can anyone help understand the structure of this sentence?

"Adj(大/小/高/矮/胖/瘦/美/醜/..) + 了（一）点儿" = "a little bit too + adj"
Note that, similar to "太 + adj + 了", "了" helps to express/emphasize the state of "excessiveness". But, unlike the former (太 + adj + 了), it is indispensable in this pattern (adj + 了（一）点儿).

"他年龄大了点儿" = "他年龄有点儿大" - "He is a little bit too old"; both are a more reserved expression than "他年龄太大了 or 他太老了 - He is too old"

Also note that without 太 and (一）点儿, "了" indicates the "change of state".

他老了 - He gets old/He is getting old.


People say:
"大了"中的“了”表示变化已经完成.
The “了”in 大了expresses that the difference is already complete.
But:
1. You can leave out 了：他年龄大点儿，他文化低点儿。
2. If I am older than you, that is no change, I will always be older than you.
So what does 了 do? It emphasises.
他年龄大了点儿，他文化低了点儿。
He's slightly older, but his level of education is a little lower.
他: his
年龄: age
大了: greater
点儿: a little
他: his
文化: schooling
低了: lower
点儿: a little
You could write: 他年纪稍大，但受教育程度稍低。
你多大了?
How old are you?

"他年龄大了点儿，他文化低了点儿", "他年龄有点儿大，他文化有点儿低" both are nice.
"他年龄大点儿了 ，他文化低点儿了 " looks confusing. "等他年龄大点儿了/等他年龄(再)大点儿" looks okay, means wait until his age is bigger/ wait until his getting older.
